# How to add box to ipywidgets interactive?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Found this code [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Flickering-and-jumping-output).

```
%matplotlib inline
from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(m, b):
    plt.figure(2)
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)
    plt.plot(x, m * x + b)
    plt.ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(f, m=(-2.0, 2.0), b=(-3, 3, 0.5))
output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '350px'
interactive_plot
```

It creates a plot that can be interacted with and doesn't flicker. I looked in the documentation but I don't know how to add a box to control this plot? For instance how would I use this hbox to update the plot?

```
items = [widgets.FloatSlider(value=5, min=0, max=10, step=0.01,
                             orientation='vertical', layout=Layout(width="15px"), readout_format='.0f') 
         for i in range(5)]
hbox = widgets.HBox(items)
hbox
```

If you know the answer please elaborate and explain why it is done like that.
I tried to call the function `f` from `observe` and it simply created new unrelated plots.
When the same function is called from interactive it works amazingly well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough idea of what is happening with an `interactive`, perhaps you can adapt it to your situation?

```py
%matplotlib inline
import ipywidgets as ipwy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import clear_output

m_widg = ipwy.FloatSlider(min=-2, max=2, step=0.5)
b_widg = ipwy.FloatSlider(min=-3, max=3, step=0.5)
out = ipwy.Output(layout = ipwy.Layout(height='350px'))
display(ipwy.VBox(children=(m_widg, b_widg, out)))


def f(*args):
    out.clear_output()
    m = m_widg.value
    b = b_widg.value
    plt.figure(2)
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)
    plt.plot(x, m * x + b)
    plt.ylim(-5, 5)
    with out:
        clear_output()
        plt.show()
    
m_widg.observe(f, names=['value'])
b_widg.observe(f, names=['value'])
```

Comment: Thanks but no, this does flicker.